# Clojure macro problem

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to create a function to create a new basewith another struct as a base, and as a start I attempted to make a macro that would create a new struct with the same fields as the old one.  The macro I have which i thought *should* do this is below, but it is giving the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Can't use qualified name as parameter: user/p1__132
```

Macro:

```
(defmacro prototype [structure obj]
  `(apply struct ~structure (map #(~obj %) (keys ~obj))))
```

Example of use:

```
(defstruct bintree :data :left :right)
(def a (struct bintree 3))
(prototype bintree a)
```

The desired output in this case would be

```
{:data 3 :left nil :right nil}
```

Comment: I'm new to clojure but I found this link:  http://osdir.com/ml/java.clojure.user/2008-03/msg00108.html

Comment: could you add the desired output to the example of use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link seth posted as a comment to your question contains the answer (the culprit is the way arguments to anonymous functions are handled); the following, using a gensym argument, should work:

```
(defmacro prototype [structure obj]
  `(apply struct ~structure (map (fn [x#] (~obj x#)) (keys ~obj))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fixed version:

```
(defmacro prototype [structure obj]
  `(apply struct ~structure (map ~obj (keys ~obj))))
```

Why does this need to be a macro? A function works too:

```
(defn prototype [structure obj]
  (apply struct structure (map obj (keys obj))))
```

Why do you want to copy the structure? Structures are immutable so copying them is not useful. This function does the same thing as the one above:

```
(defn prototype [structure obj] obj)
```

If you want to create a new structure with additional keys&values, use `assoc`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `#()` inside a macro.

```
user> (macroexpand-1 `(foo #(bar %) baz))
(user/foo (fn* [user/p1__2047] (user/bar user/p1__2047)) user/baz)
```

Not that the `fn*` form has a namespace-qualified symbol in its parameter list.  That's the error you're getting.  You should avoid this kind of special reader syntax in macros and use the long forms instead.